# Expressing Ada-style constraints and subtypes in Scala?

Tags: scala, ada

Is there a practical way in Scala to express *ranges* on numeric values and types, in the style of Ada?

```
-- newtype derived from Float
type Pounds is new Float;

-- constraint on an individual variable
Cat_Weight: Pounds range 0.0 .. 10.0; 

 -- constraint on an entire subtype of Float
subtype People_Pounds is Pounds range 0.0 .. 300.0;
```

(OK, not the most realistic example, but adapted from [Ada Safe and Secure](http://www.adacore.com/uploads_gems/Ada_Safe_and_Secure_Booklet.pdf). As I understand it, range checks in Ada are runtime checks, which throw an exception if violated, and can be disabled in production if desired.)

Ideally using an unboxed representation, but interested in any practical solution. [Value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) don't seem to be an option, at least not in isolation:

```
class Month(val m: Int) extends AnyVal {
    assert(m >= 1 && m <= 12) // Does not compile: assertion not allowed
}
```

We could create a case class with an `assert` or `require`:

```
case class Month2(val m: Int) {
  require(m >= 1 && m <= 12)
}
```

but then this isn't an Integer subtype, and we'd probably need to give it a Numeric typeclass instance - is this the only way?

Comment: You can use `require(m >= 1 && m <= 12)`

Comment: Not in a value class - `assert` and `require` both produce compile error `"this statement is not allowed in value class"`

Comment: Would the [`JScience`](http://jscience.org) implementation of [tag:jsr-275] be of use?

Comment: Jscience (and similar Scala libraries like [Squants](http://www.squants.com/) are impressive and useful, but they seem to deal with specifying/constraining the *dimensions* rather than the *values*)

Comment: Implemented an example of what the question suggested. Using case classes and type classes to encode it. https://gist.github.com/cvogt/b224af4b70a0c7d9a4cd